What does merge xx into xxx mean
In my repo, I have one branch (branch_1) and from it, I have been committing some changes. Then I created a new branch from branch_1, branch_2.
Master---
         \
          Branch_1--commit1--commit2
                                   \
                                    Branch_2 (current branch) 

Meanwhile, a review was done in Branch_1 and I made some changes:
  Master---
             \
             Branch1--squashed commit1,commit2--commit3--commit4
                                       \
                                        Branch2 (current branch)

How can I now apply the last changes of branch_1 in branch_2?
What it means to merge branch_1 onto branch_2 and vice versa.

"Merge onto" doesn't mean anything. There's only "merge into" and then there's "rebase onto". Do note that your ASCII art can not reflect the actual Git history, because squashing two commits will not affect other branches.

Does this answer your question? How to rebase after squashing commits in the original branch?

Note that what you call Branch_1 would actually be commit2, as the label Branch_1 identifies a commit as a branch head and is updated every time you commit to a branch.

Technically speaking, what you're asking for is a rebase (which is laymens terms means moving the point where you branch off around on the trunk), a merge is a superset of it.
However, merging Branch1 into the current branch (Branch2) will do what you want.

What it means to merge branch_1 onto branch_2 and vice versa.

It means bringing in all the changes from one branch into another. The order is important, it is what determines what branch you're writing into.

It seems like that in your case, branch_1's changes have been already made public and available on the remote repository, while branch_2 changes are local to your repository. In this situation, it would be best to fetch or pull branch_1's new changes and rebase branch_2 on top of branch_1.
# integrating new changes into branch_1
git checkout branch_1
git pull

# integrating branch_1' changes into branch_2
git checkout branch_1
git rebase branch_1

This operation will basically re-write on top of branch_1 each commit made on branch_2 after the divergence. Like so, the new changes in branch_1 will be present in branch_2, with a more linear history than merging the two branches back and forth (this is assuming that branch_2 will be merged into branch_1 or a master branch at some point).
Instead, in regard of your second question:

What it means to merge branch_1 onto branch_2 and vice versa?

Merging simply means to combine together two or more histories of changes since their divergence. The merge commit created after the operation becomes the node from which you can refer the parent histories in the commit graph, allowing you to see the changes from the other branch (branch_1) in your target branch (branch_2). Quoting the documentation of the git merge command.

Incorporates changes from the named commits (since the time their histories diverged from the current branch) into the current branch.

Also this approach will let you have branch_1's changes into branch_2. However, as said before, the history will look more entangled and less readable.
git checkout branch_1
git pull

git checkout branch_2
git merge branch_1

